# How to run Oracle APEX application on Client side PC

Tags: oracle, connection, client-server, oracle-apex

How can I run Oracle APEX application on Client PC which is connected remotely to Database server side PC through Oracle Client Service software.

Oracle XE 11.2g
Oracle APEX version 19
Client service sotfware version 21.1.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote an application. When you run it, all you need is a web browser. There's the application URL in browser's address line. It looks like

> http://your.server:8084/apex/f?p=120:1:3120653734023:::::

Client (person) needs this part of it (`120` represents `APP_ID`):

> http://your.server:8084/apex/f?p=120

Send it to the client" who will just have to click on it and - if you're in the same network - get application's log in window. If you also provided username and password, client will be able to run the application.

Therefore, you don't have to install any Oracle software on client's PC.

Comment: Yes i figure it out.

Comment: But you have enable remote connection with the following code; 
    execute dbms_xdb.setListenerLocalAccess(l_access => FALSE);